# When does function $(\log_b(x))^p$ change its curvature?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, graphing-functions, curves

Consider $(\log_b(x))^p$ where $b$ is   a  constant $>1$; $x, p \in \mathbb R_+$.

As we increase the value of $p$ (starting from 1), at specific value of $p$, the curve changes its shape from concave to convex, specifically for $x\ge 1$.  [See Curve Transition](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1fzp8z5ris).

So the question is:

1. At what value of $p$, in terms of $b$, the transition of curvature (from concave to convex) occurs?
2. How to find it mathematically?

Comment: is the equation $$\log_b(x)^{p}$$ and what kind of number is $p$?

Comment: p is Real number.

Comment: what do you mean with 'the curve changes its curvature' the inflection points?

Comment: Inflection point changes with change in plot, as we increase the value of p.

By change in curvature I mean:  The plot transition from Concave downwards to Concave upwards shape.

Comment: you must compute the second derivative with respect to $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As we increase the value of $p$ (starting from $1$), at specific value of $p$, the curve changes its shape from concave to convex

No, it only seems that way, because of the restricted window in which you see the graph. The function $(\log_b x)^p$ is not convex for any value $p>0$.

It suffices to consider $\ln x$, because the base only contributes a constant factor $\ln b$ to the denominator. The second derivative of $(\ln x)^p$ is 
$$\frac{p(p-\ln x-1)(\ln x)^{p-2}}{x^2}$$

- If $0<p\le 1$, the second derivative is negative for all $x>1$, so the function is concave
- If $p>1$, the second derivative changes sign at the point where $\ln x = p-1$. This inflection point will be far off to the right when $p$ is large, but it's there.

That said, the function *is* convex on $(1,\infty)$ when $p<0$.